# recursion factiorial. Why do I get NaN

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have this simple factorial function. It works on recursion. the number that I get at the end however is NaN.  I am expecting an output of 6, factorial of 3. Is the problem because I defined x as a global variable ? and if so how do you define a variable as local inside the function without making it change in recursion.

```
var x;
function factorial(num)
{

    if (num > 0) {
       x =  num * factorial(num - 1);
    }
    return x;
}


console.log(factorial(3));
```

Comment: `var x;` - Initialization?

Comment: When you implement recursive algorithms it's a good idea to maintain the state in arguments, not rely on free variables. At the moment your implementation cannot calculate factorial twice.

Comment: is there a way to initialize it inside the function but not have initialize every time the function runs, because that is a problem in recursion @thefourtheye

Comment: "because that is a problem in recursion" --- no, it's not.

Comment: really ? so I could just define it as local variable and it won't get redefined when function is being called recursively and updating x ? @zerkms

Comment: @Mozein it's a **local** variable. Every call it has its own distinct value.

Comment: currently in my code ? no its global i initialized it outside the function.. @zerkms unless im missing something

Comment: @Mozein not currently in your code, I replied to your last comment.

Comment: How about this solution, which avoids recursion

`function factorial(num) {
    var result = 1;
    while(num)
        result *= num--;
    return result;
}`

Comment: @Brett yes. but Id like to use recursion. I believe time efficiency wise is faster. Even if not I would like to understand it better.

Comment: @Mozein We can do that, but what if you want to call it the second time? So, better follow zerkms's suggestion.

Comment: "time efficiency wise is faster" --- o_O

Comment: @Brett—factorial is the *Hello world* of recursive functions. You don't write it because it's useful, but because you can. ;-)

Comment: @RobG lol. PS: raise your hands who used a factorial function in real life usage in last year?

Comment: @zerkms it's not ? I believe brett's anwser is O(n) while recursively it's O(logn)

Comment: @Mozein "while recursively it's O(logn)" --- what? Well, it's not :-) You cannot multiply `N` numbers in less than `N` steps.

Comment: @Mozein—everything that can be done with recursion can be done sequentially and will almost certainly be a lot faster (i.e. recursion is slow, but usually uses less code). Think of all those function calls and stack that needs to be maintained vs a simple loop.

Comment: @Mozein: Both are O(n). Recursion is just a slightly slower O(n).

Comment: got it. Thanks for the clarification. when I think of recursion I immediately think of merge sort and binary search and it gives me the idea that it is faster. however factorial actually goes through every number. sorry for this mistake

Comment: @zerkms: o/ Mostly when computing probabilities, primarily for binomial distributions.

Comment: @Mozein: merge sort and binary search are rather nice *algorithms* that happen to implement easily using recursion (but as RobG says, can be unrolled to non-recursive iteration, it's just ugly). The recursive factorial and the iterative factorial happen to be the exactly same algorithm, and thus have exactly the same complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `num > 0`, you define `x`. What is `x` when `num` is *not* `> 0`?

HINT: Should be `1`. Isn't. :)

HINT2: Try `console.log(1 * undefined)`

P.S.: Yes, `var x` should go inside the function. No, it doesn't do anything bad in this case, but it could.

Comment: "*…it doesn't do anything bad…*", err, it did. ;-)

Comment: @RobG: No, it doesn't. It gets assigned (or not), then immediately returned.  If you just stick `x = 1` inside the function, it is not dependent on the previous value. (And if you don't, the code doesn't work anyway, not the fault of the variable being global.)

Comment: I actually ended up not defining any new variable. just returned the number multiplied by the function recursive call, and I placed an if(num==0) statement to return 1. Thanks for the hints though ! understood my errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `x` with value first.

```
var x = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's investigate detaily what happened:

```
f(3) = 3 * f(2);
f(2) = 2 * f(1);
f(1) = 1 * f(0);
```

For `f(0)`, it directly goes to `return x;`, while your global variable `var x;` is not initialized, thus `f(0)` return `undefined`, and `1 * factorial(0)` get `NaN`, propagates to the final result.

One solution is not to use global variable:

```
function factorial(num)
{
    var x = 1;
    if (num > 0) {
       x =  num * factorial(num - 1);
    }
    return x;
}
console.log(factorial(3));  // 6
```

Comment: The explanation is incorrect. `factorial(0)` returns `undefined`, not `NaN`. `NaN` happens at `factorial(1)`, at `1 * factorial(0)`, and propagates to all higher numbers.